# using fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following using fundamental theorem of calculus. $$F(x)={d\over dx }\int_0^{3x}\sin ((x-t)^2)\,dt$$

I tried just substituting 3x into the equation but i get the wrong answer. What should be the right way to approaching this question?

Comment: $\int \sin x^2 dx$ can't be written using elementary functions, You do have $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^b f(t)dt = f(b) - f(a)$

Comment: I suspect your question is this: If $F: x \mapsto \int_{0}^{3x}\sin (x-t)^{2}dt$, find $F'$; right?

Comment: @GudsonChou : That's a $\frac{d}{dx}$ over there already.

Comment: @JohnMa Then I am not sure what is to be found?

Comment: @GudsonChou : Evaluate $F(x)$ (I know what you are thinking. It's just a different way to ask the same question)

Comment: but the answer given is $sin(x^2)+2sin(4x^2)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First apply substitution $u=t-x$ to find:

$$\int_{0}^{3x}\sin\left(\left(x-t\right)^{2}\right)dt=\int_{-x}^{2x}\sin u^{2}du=\int_{0}^{2x}\sin u^{2}du+\int_{-x}^{0}\sin u^{2}du=$$$$\int_{0}^{2x}\sin u^{2}du+\int_{0}^{x}\sin u^{2}du$$

Defining $G\left(x\right):=\int_{0}^{x}\sin u^{2}du$ this equals $G(2x)+G(x)$, and we have: $$G'\left(x\right)=\sin x^{2}$$
so the derivative of $G\left(2x\right)+G\left(x\right)$ is: $$2\sin\left(2x\right)^{2}+\sin x^{2}=2\sin4x^{2}+\sin x^{2}$$

Comment: why does the upper and lower bound change to 2x and -x respectively?

Comment: I repaired. Here $\int^0_{-x}=\int^x_0$ because of the nature of the integrand.

Comment: i meant why do you have to change it to 2x and -x?

Comment: $\int^{2x}_{-x}=\int^{2x}_{0}+\int^{0}_{-x}$. In this form (*one* border with $x$ in it) you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus without troubles. If $0<t<3x$ then $-x<u<2x$ if that's what you mean.

Comment: I am in agreement with your answer..But ,would you please let me know why Newton-Leibnitz formula $(d/dx)\int^{\phi(x)}_{\psi(x)}f(t)dt=f[{\phi(x)}]{\phi'(x)}-f[{\psi(x)}]{\psi'(x)}$,fails here?

Comment: @kilimanjaro because $x$ is present in the integrand $f$.

Comment: But while integrating w.r.t $t$,isn't it assumed that $x$ is constant(w.r.t $t$)?

Comment: @kilimanjaro Yes it is, but the method fails anyway. E.g. try it out on the more simple $\int_{0}^{x}t+xdx=\frac{3}{2}x^{2}$. It has derivative $3x$. Not $x+x$. From now on you are a warned man :-).

Comment: So Newton-Leibnitz is valid ONLY WHEN $ f(t) $(with no $x$)is integrand  in $(d/dx)\int^{\phi(x)}_{\psi(x)}f(t)dt=f[{\phi(x)}]{\phi'(x)}-f[{\psi(x)}]{\psi'(‌​x)}$.Isn't it?

Comment: @kilimanjaro Yes.